# Is there a c++ std solution to filter and reduce without creating a copy?

Tags: c++, algorithm, std

I want to find the minimum element of a filtered list. In Python, I would write:

```py
it = (x for x in [1, 8, 4, 3] if x % 2 == 0)
min(it, default=None)
```

I hoped that the c++ equivalent would read something like:

```cpp
const std::vector<int> array {1, 8, 4, 3};

const auto arr_end = std::end(array);
auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(array), arr_end, [](int value) { return value % 2 == 0; });
auto jt = std::min_element(it, arr_end);

if (jt != arr_end) {
    std::cout << "Min even element is: " << *jt << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "No even element exists!" << std::endl;
}
```

The expected result is 4, but of course the actual result is 3. The reason: `find_if` skips to 8. Then from 8 to end the min element is chosen, which is 3.

My question: Is there a way to create an iterator over all even values that can be used to find the minimum element? I am not allowed to use boost, create a copy or to write to `array`. We are using c++17.

Comment: Sadly STL algorithms cannot be easily composed, you would have to create a filtered iterator by hand. This has been remedied by C++20 ranges which work similarly to Python's generators.

Comment: @Quimby `by hand` or as is usually possible, use one that was created by someone else's hand.

Comment: You can also have a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798686/applying-stdmin-element-only-on-elments-that-satisfy-a-condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't an answer in `std` as of C++17. In C++20 you can use `std::ranges::filter_view`, outside of `std` you can use `ranges::filter_view` from the [range-v3 library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), which was the demonstration implementation for the C++20 ranges proposal.

```
auto filtered = ranges::filter_view(array, [](int value) { return value % 2 == 0; });
auto it = std::min_element(filtered.begin(), filtered.end());

if (it != filtered.end()) {
    std::cout << "Min even element is: " << *jt << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "No even element exists!" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question: Is there a way to create an iterator over all even values that can be used to find the minimum element?

Yes!

It's slightly unfortunate that you're limited to C++17 with no Boost, because you ideally want *ranges* - specifically [`ranges::filter_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view) etc. which was added in C++20, and preceded by the Boost.Range library.

You may possibly be able to use the intermediate [`experimental range extension`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges).

If none of those are viable, you can of course write your own `filtered_iterator` to use with `std::min_element`.

It's not much fun: although it's probably more reusable (and easier to test) than encoding all the logic into a single lambda, it's a lot of work if you're *not* planning to reuse it. Also, C++ iterators aren't ideally suited to emulating a Python-style generator, as demonstrated by the redundant end iterator `e_` and the copy-assignment operator. You can't elide the end & predicate members of the filtered end iterator either, because both iterators usually need to be the same type.

```
template <typename BaseIterator, typename UnaryPredicate>
class filter_iterator
{
    BaseIterator i_;
    BaseIterator e_;
    UnaryPredicate pred_;
public:
    using reference = typename std::iterator_traits<BaseIterator>::reference;
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<BaseIterator>::value_type;

    filter_iterator(filter_iterator &&) = default;
    filter_iterator(filter_iterator const&) = default;
    filter_iterator(BaseIterator i, BaseIterator e, UnaryPredicate p)
    : i_(i), e_(e), pred_(p)
    {}
    filter_iterator& operator=(filter_iterator &&) = default;
    filter_iterator& operator=(filter_iterator const& other) {
        i_ = other.i_;
        e_ = other.e_;
        // This is questionable, because we can't copy the predicate without adding
        // a level of indirection (ie, always wrapping it in std::function).
        // For now, just assume it is stateless for convenience.
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(filter_iterator const& other) const
    {
        return i_ == other.i_;
    }
    filter_iterator& operator++() {
        // We could check i_ is not already e_ here,
        // but the caller is required to check this outside anyway
        i_ = find_if(next(i_), e_, pred_);
        return *this;
    }
    filter_iterator operator++(int) const {
        filter_iterator i(*this);
        ++i;
        return i;
    }

    reference operator*() { return *i_; }
    std::add_const_t<reference> operator*() const { return *i_; }
};
template <typename BaseIterator, typename UnaryPredicate>
bool operator!=(filter_iterator<BaseIterator, UnaryPredicate> const& a,
                filter_iterator<BaseIterator, UnaryPredicate> const& b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}
```

Then the wrapper function hides most of this ugliness for us:

```
template <typename BaseIterator, typename UnaryPredicate>
std::pair<filter_iterator<BaseIterator, UnaryPredicate>,
          filter_iterator<BaseIterator, UnaryPredicate>>
          filter(BaseIterator b, BaseIterator e, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    using f = filter_iterator<BaseIterator, UnaryPredicate>;
    auto fbegin = find_if(b, e, p);
    return {f{fbegin, e, p}, {e, e, p}};
}
```

and we can use it like:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> a {7, 1, 8, 4, 3, 2};
    auto be = filter(a.begin(), a.end(),
                     [](int i){ return (i%2) == 0;});
    auto min = std::min_element(be.first, be.second);
    return *min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are limited at c++17 there is no solution without making a copy.

If you can transition to C++ 20 the solution is pretty easy. C++ 20 introduced the std::views concept and added the `<ranges>` library. The concept of std::view is to **not** create a copy of the underlying container, and it does not modifies the actual values of the container. Behind the scenes the views are actually iterators(actually it is a bit more but lets stay at the basics)

So in your case you could something like this

```cpp
const std::vector<int> array {1, 8, 4, 3};

auto isEven = [](auto i) { return i % 2 == 0; };

//This is actually an iterator pair(begin, end)
//No copies of the container ever made, the container does not change
auto filtered = array | std::views::filter(isEven);
auto min = std::ranges::min_element(filtered );

if (min != filtered .end())
    std::cout << "Min " << *min << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "No min\n";

//You can try to print the vector, it will be unchanged!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::find_if` does not filter the vector. It only returns the first element for which the predicate is `true`. I suppose there is an elegant solution using ranges. The rather inelegant way is to use a custom comparator with `min_element`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const std::vector<int> array {1, 8, 4, 3};
    std::vector<float> x;
    if (array.size()) {
        auto it = std::min_element(begin(array),end(array),
         [](auto a, auto b){
             if ((a % 2) && (b % 2)) return a < b;
             if (a % 2) return false;
             if (b % 2) return true;
             return a < b;
         });
         if (*it % 2 == 0) std::cout << *it;
    }

}
```

Odd elements are considered to be not `<` than other elements. When both are odd or both are even the "normal" `<` is used. Output is:

```
4
```

Note that I have to check `if (*it % 2 == 0)` because when there is no even element then the call to `min_element` will return an iterator to the smallest odd element.

PS: The tricky part of custom comparators is to get [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) correct. The above comparator can be written in a more concise way (thanks to Jarod42) like this:

```
return std::tuple{ bool{a%2} , a} < std::tuple{ bool{b%2} , b};
```

Tuples have a `operator<` that implements a strict weak ordering (given that the elements type provide one), hence writing it this way it is much easier to convice yourself that the comparator really is a strict weak ordering.

Comment: Instead of the `if` in comparer (which might easily break strict ordering), I tend to transform value in tuple: `return std::tuple{is_odd(a), a} < std::tuple{is_odd(b), b};`